# Map float to color with non linear scaling

Tags: graphics, mapping, data-visualization, color-mapping

I'am trying to map colors from a range of `[0,1]`.

Let's say I have a function like that

```
public Vector3 mapToColor(float value){
    // Apply a scaling to value
    // Derive a color from the scaling in HSV
    // Convert this color to RGB and return it
    Vector3 hsv = new Vector3(value*360,1,1);
    return toRGB(hsv);
}
```

Right now I map from the range `[0,1]` to `[0,360]` by multiplying the input value with `360` and use it as `Hue`.
Now I want to use a non linear mapping/scaling. But I dont understand the mapping process. If I use `hue=log(1+value)*360` the result is wrong.
So how do I linearly scale my input `value` ?

Comment: What is a wrong result and what would be correct? *Non-linear* alone is a bit vague.

Comment: Difficult to explain. The first example represents basically a rainbow colormap. When for the exact code I use log(1+value) then when value becomes 1 this results in a hue of log(2)*360 = 249 . Which (in my opinion) is wrong because the end and the start of the rainbow colormap should represent the color with hue=0 and hue=360

Comment: Depends on the logarithm you use. Divide by `log(2)` and you are back to the `0-360°` range.

Comment: I don't see the benefit for this approach? "2" is dynamic, so dividing by log(x) everytime I would get 360° all the time, which will do no interpolation at all?

Comment: I didn't say divide by `log(x)`. I said divide by `log(2)`.